# how to hover scale button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  buttonStyle: {
    color: "red",
    background: "black",
    "&hover": {
      transform: "scale(10)",
      background: "black",
    },
  },
});
```

> i what to button to be flat without hover effect and to be scale by 10% and i
> do not know how?

```
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Heloo</h1>
      <Button
        className={classes.buttonStyle}
        style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
        variant="contained"
        onClick={() => butttonHandler()}
      >
        helooo
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: try `transform: { scale:10 }`

Comment: On hover he must scale by 10%

Comment: Use ‘10%’ then instead of 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have the wrong CSS selector for styling the hover effect. It should be `&:hover` instead of `&hover`.
2. You should use `transform: "scale(1.1)"` to scale the button by 10% on hover. Here's the [documentation on `scale()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale())
3. You can add the `disableElevation` prop to the `Button` component. It disables elevation on hover and keep the button "flat"

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  buttonStyle: {
    color: "red",
    background: "black",

    "&:hover": {
      transform: "scale(1.1)", // Scale by 10%
      background: "black"
    }
  }
});
```

```
  return (
    <Button
      className={classes.buttonStyle}
      disableElevation
      variant="contained"
    >
      helooo
    </Button>
  );
```

[image: Edit on Code Sandbox]

Note: In your original code, you are setting the button background to be black in your `makeStyles` styling, but then you are overwriting it with `style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}` inside your `Button` component.